# Is it possible to use the RID (Runtime Identifier) for conditional dependencies in a .NET project file?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a package that is specific to `linux-x64` RID.

How do I add this package as a dependency in my project file with a condition on the RID?

This is not quite what I am looking for because it does not check the architecture:

```xml
Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform('Linux'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following condition to check if the RID is `linux-x64`:

```
Condition="$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::RuntimeIdentifier.Equals('linux-x64'))"
```